# In C#, what would be the closest counterpart of Java's JavaFX?

Tags: c#, javafx, 2d

I've learned Java in the past, and for making 2D graphics, it seemed that JavaFX was about the only option for making graphics. (Swing and possibly some other stuff weren't updated much anymore.) Regardless of whether that is true or not, I recently started learning C#, and I couldn't find any such equivalents. There seem to be several different things that can be used but various places have criticized the speed or usefulness of a few of them.

To be a little less abstract, I'm looking to display 2D graphics.
a) I would like to be able to control individual pixels. eg. Progressively rendering fractals.
b) I would like to be able to display existing images in quick succession. Basically animations from pictures.
c) I would like for it to be interactable. Being able to respond to keyboard and mouse buttons etc.
d) General application functionality like pre-defined buttons, sliders, text boxes, or vector graphics or w/e would be nice, but not necessary for my current purposes.

Is there a standard / more popular / faster / better option for these, or what would you recommend?

Comment: You can try `WPF`

Comment: I think WPF - [Window Presentation Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/) can handle all of this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JavaFX compare to WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016470/how-does-javafx-compare-to-wpf)

Comment: If you're looking for something to run on Mac or Linux then WPF will not run on those.