# MVVM pattern in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvvm, simple-mvvm

I want to make a `mvvm` project on java. But I can not find a sample project. There are a few Android samples but I don't want to make an  Android-project. So how can I make a project with the `mvvm` pattern?

I am trying to create a desktop application on which there are combo boxes and a data-grid. The app must connect to a database (i.e. MySQL) and the data-grid must be filled with data. Any changes on the combo boxes must change the grid's content. Maybe I want to make `CRUD`-operation on later steps.

So any suggestions...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [JavaFX framework](http://javafx.com/). It was already mentioned in a couple of other stackoverflow questions:

- [How does JavaFX compare to WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016470/how-does-javafx-compare-to-wpf)
- [Pros and Cons of JavaFX and Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866056/pros-and-cons-of-javafx-and-silverlight)

You may also find [this blog post](http://fxexperience.com/2011/10/fxml-why-it-rocks-and-the-next-phase/) very interesting. It mentions [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) (a pattern highly related to MVVM) and walks you trough basic JavaFX concepts regarding FXML (smth. like XAML in WPF).

EDIT: Simmilar question on stackoverlow

#### [Is there anything similar to WPF and MVVM in Java world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984828/is-there-anything-similar-to-wpf-and-mvvm-in-java-world)

Comment: Thank you but my project have to be use mvvm not anything like "higly related". my boss do not allow me to use a pattern other than mvvm even if it is much more useful. But still thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

In 2012 I published an article on a Java framework doing MVVM ("presentation model"), MVP ("passive view") and a hybrid MVVMP/MVC ("supervising controller") on the IBM developer website. In 2023 the link was broke. Here is a copy shared out of my personal Dropbox folder:

[Implementing event-driven GUI patterns using the ZK Java AJAX framework](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/mh4o16jw3k4ctvwewg6wc/zk-patterns.docx?rlkey=c776l7mqyyhpjhqdx2v4d7asi&dl=0)

It has full source code which deployed on three different PaaS cloud services over at [github](https://github.com/simbo1905/ZkToDo2).

The source code has links to demos that worked in 2012 running on free tier cloud providers. Those were shut down some time in the past decade.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasS. I dug up a copy and provided a link to the source over at GitHub. Please let me know if the new link works. Thx